# How can I get an sqlite3.Row-like row factory using mysql-connector-python?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I want to make it clear that what I'm asking for is not just to get a dictionary, I know that can easily be done with `cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)`. `sqlite3`'s `sqlite3.Row` is special in that it can be accessed with both keys and indexes, like so:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT somestuff FROM sometable WHERE somecolumn = 'somevalue'")
print(cursor.fetchone()[0])
print(cursor.fetchone()['somestuff'])
```

Is it possible to do this with mysql-connector-python, preferably in some officially supported way, like in sqlite3?

Comment: there is afaik no subcalss for that https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cursor-subclasses.html

Comment: @nbk You're right in the sense that you can't use the syntax I specified in the question, however you can use named tuples, which are, essentially, what I was asking for. Thanks for helping me find this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursornamedtuple.html

Comment: hm good that you told me, i woukd never had guessed that  you are4 looking for this